# Dev Container commands throw error in VSCode using WSL and Dev Containers extensions

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer

I'm trying to work on a new project for someone. Since I won't own this project in the long term, I wanted to keep my computer clean of dependencies concerning the project, hence why using Docker. I also like working in a Unix-like system, but not having a Mac, I opted for WSL (as I don't currently have a Linux distro ready for development)

I went through the Docker & WSL2 setup and created a new directory in the WSL filesystem. Additionally, I wanted to use VSCode's Dev Containers extension to open the project directory from inside the docker container, so to speak. Hence, I run the VSCode command `Add Dev Container Configuration Files...` that the extension provides, and choose a Linux universal docker image

While that command doesn't give me any issues, any of the commands that consists of reopening the project directory in the docker container throws this error:

```
Command "${VSCode command that I just tried running}" resulted in an error

Shell server terminated (code: 2, signal: null)

/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

[dev containers unterminated quoted string error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IW5l.png)

I have no clue how to fix this error. I tried reinstalling VSCode and the extensions, restarting the system, checked my `.bashrc` for errors, to no avail. I can use CLI docker, build and run images/containers just fine. I can open interactive shells inside running containers in the terminal. It's just when it comes to VSCode, any command that consists of connecting to the container, such as "Reopen in container" or "Rebuild and reopen in container" result in the same error above

I feel like the solution might be obvious and that I'm just missing something here. But I've spent like 6 hours trying to solve this issue, and none of those hours has been spent on actual project development funnily enough